# Add an extra toplevel to entire website, and start with a clean version of the application

Tags: php, sql, symfony, design-patterns, doctrine

**The problem:**

We have a web application (in Symfony 2.8) with +- 125 tables filled with data. Now our client asks to add an extra top-level named "Division". And when they create a new Division, they get a blanc copy of the application to start working in. So almost like a new clean sheet.

The users stay the same, some will get access to 1 Division, some to multiple.

Important: **More Divisions will come in the future, the client admins can just press "new division"**.

We are now going through the whole application:

- The **top-level** entities get an extra property Division (via a DivisionTrait) added to them...
- changing every single query by adding something like `AND division.id = $session->get('current_division')` in all *controllers*.
- Injecting this division id in all **form types** and also extend every query.
- And of course a lot of testing and debugging

But this is **a lot** of work.

**The question:**

What are the options or design patterns so we can achieve this in an easier way? I'm sure we are not the first ones with this problem. ;)

Comment: Why do you have SQL queries in the controllers? Looks like there might be a lot of deeper issue in that codebase =)

Comment: OK, you are right, we have to move queries out of the controllers but that is not my question ;)

Comment: You are not going to have a different database for each division?

Comment: Indeed, we want to keep everything in 1 database. Furthermore, I guess it is possible that in the future some data will be available for multiple divisions. The client changes his mind often, but no worries. It's a good client, they always pay for the extra hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are approaching this wrong ... or your description of the issue is misleading.

As I see it, each Division has their own application (with their own domain). With their own independent database. What is share are the user accounts, which means that you need to create a 3rd application: authentication system, which can identify your users and check their authorization for accessing one of the divisions.

So, make an authentication system.

Associate the shared identity with an internal "users" table, that you will used for ACL/RBAC, but leave the login to be handled why the external app.

This way you wont have to manually edit all the code and try to squeeze a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: The clients admin user needs to be able to just press "new division" and start working, without our interference.

Comment: Then I hope you told the client, that it will take at least a month, since you need to completely re-design the entire thing. Not only you need to change the authentication system, but the authorization will also need to be change. And multiple table will need `division_id` foreign column added. It's a mess and there are no good options - just lot of manual labor for rewriting everything :(